# How to export data after finding nodes with a selector

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I succeeded with an RVest tutorial on web scraping and would like to know:
1) How I can remove the "\n"? before exporting the file?
2) How can I export the data into a CSV file?

PS Here's the link to the tutorial mentioned above: 
https://blog.rstudio.com/2014/11/24/rvest-easy-web-scraping-with-r/

I'm very new to R so any help is appreciated.

This is the code I used:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
lego_movie <- html("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1490017/")

### movie rating ###

lego_movie %>%
  html_node("strong span") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  as.numeric()


### actors names ###

lego_movie %>%
  html_nodes(".primary_photo+ td") %>%
  html_text()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pull from the [alt] attribute of the associated image and you don't need to do any extra string manipulation. No point my duplicating the existing answer about writing to csv.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

lego_movie <- read_html("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1490017/")

### actors names ###

lego_movie %>% html_nodes(".cast_list td:first-child [alt]") %>% html_attr(., "alt")
# lego_movie %>% html_nodes(".cast_list td:nth-child(1) [alt]") %>% html_attr(., "alt")
```

---

Side note: A lot of that info is stored in a script tag as json

```
library(jsonlite)
library(rvest)

lego_movie <- read_html("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1490017/")
data <- jsonlite::fromJSON(lego_movie %>%html_node("[type='application/ld+json']")%>%html_text())
#example
print(data$actor)
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove `\n` or any other leading or trailing spaces or tabs, you can just do add `str_replace_all("[ \t\r\n]" , "")` to the end and save it to a variable because you want to save it as a csv:

```
actor_list <- lego_movie %>%
     html_nodes(".primary_photo+ td") %>%
     html_text() %>% str_replace_all("[ \t\r\n]" , "")
```

Output:

```
 [1] "WillArnett"     "ElizabethBanks" "CraigBerry"     "AlisonBrie"     "DavidBurrows"  
 [6] "AnthonyDaniels" "CharlieDay"     "AmandaFarinos"  "KeithFerguson"  "WillFerrell"   
[11] "WillForte"      "DaveFranco"     "MorganFreeman"  "ToddHansen"     "JonahHill"
```

To save as CSV do:

```
df <- data.frame(actor_list)
write.csv(df, 'actor_list.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. However I get this message : Error in data.frame(actor_list) : object 'actor_list' not found. What should I do?

Comment: May be because you forgot to assign your statement to `actor_list`. Look at my answer, it should be: `actor_list <- lego_movie %>%
     html_nodes(".primary_photo+ td") %>%
     html_text() %>% str_replace_all("[ \t\r\n]" , "")`